# Expo IAP: How to check subscription status (active or expired)?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo, in-app-purchase

We get the purchase history using [InAppPurchases.getPurchaseHistoryAsync(options)](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/in-app-purchases/#inapppurchasesgetpurchasehistoryasyncoptions), but this only includes the original purchaseTime, which is not very useful for an auto-renewing subscription.

Comment: did you find any solution for this?